# Ajax not working in wicket for me

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I wanted to test some AJAX DropDown in wicket 6.5 (tried wicket 6.6 and had same problems).

I created my wicket test project using quickstart wicket page - http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket -DarchetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=6.6.0 -DgroupId=net.betlista -DartifactId=tests.wicket-6.6 -DarchetypeRepository=https://repository.apache.org/ -DinteractiveMode=false

I changed `HomaPage` to my `LoadableDropDownTestPage` in `getHomePage()` of generated `WicketApplication` class.

Java code for LoadableDropDownTestPage is:

```java
package net.betlista;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.IAjaxIndicatorAware;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.OnChangeAjaxBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

public class LoadableDropDownTestPage extends WebPage implements IAjaxIndicatorAware {

    public LoadableDropDownTestPage() {
        addComponents();
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

        FormObject formObject = new FormObject();
        Form<FormObject> form = new Form<FormObject>("loadableDropDownTestForm", Model.of(formObject));
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

        final DropDownChoice<String> countryDD = new LoadableDropDown("countryDD", new PropertyModel<String>(formObject, "country"));
        countryDD.setChoices(new CountryLoadableModel());
        countryDD.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        countryDD.setRequired(true);
        countryDD.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

        final DropDownChoice<String> cityDD = new LoadableDropDown("cityDD", new PropertyModel<String>(formObject, "city"));
        cityDD.setChoices(new CityLoadableModel());
        cityDD.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        cityDD.setRequired(true);
        cityDD.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

        countryDD.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("country DD changed");
                target.add(cityDD);
            }
        });

        form.add(countryDD);
        form.add(cityDD);

        form.add(new AjaxButton("ab") {} );

        add(form);
    }

    static class LoadableDropDown extends DropDownChoice<String> {

        public LoadableDropDown(String id, IModel<String> model) {
            super(id);
            setModel(model);
        }

    }

    static class FormObject implements Serializable {
        String country;
        String city;
    }

    class CountryLoadableModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<String>> {

        @Override
        protected List<String> load() {
            System.out.println("loading CountryLoadableModel");
            List<String> result = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "CR", "SR" } );
            return result;
        }

    }

    class CityLoadableModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<String>> {

        List<String> choices = new LinkedList<String>();

        @Override
        protected List<String> load() {
            System.out.println("loading CityLoadableModel");
            if (choices.isEmpty()) {
                choices.add("1");
            } else {
                int size = choices.size();
                choices.add(Integer.toString(size+1));
            }

            return choices;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() {
        return "ajaxIndicator";
    }

}
```

and HTML for page is:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

    <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>

    <form wicket:id="loadableDropDownTestForm">
        Countries: <select wicket:id="countryDD"></select><br>
        Cities: <select wicket:id="cityDD"></select><br>
        <!-- input type="submit"-->
        <button wicket:id="ab"></button>
    </form>


</html>
```

My very first problem is, that I couldn't see AJAX debug link on my page. But I think that while there is `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` I should see it.

Next problem is that when I change value in country DropDown nothing happens and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

In my code you can see, that I tried also with AjaxButton, but that didn't work too.

edit:

part of the log (it's running in DEV mode)

```
********************************************************************
*** WARNING: Wicket is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.              ***
***                               ^^^^^^^^^^^                    ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this.  ***
*** See Application#getConfigurationType() for more information. ***
********************************************************************
```

Comment: The Ajax Debug Window appears only in DEV mode. Check for any errors - both in the JS console and server logs. Check whether an Ajax call is being made with Firebug/Dev Tools. Your code is not optimal but I don't see errors.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but according to log, it runs in DEV mode... I'll try in Firebug also.

Comment: I can't see any AJAX call in firebug :-/

Comment: For one, your HTML misses the body tag. Second, the markup id referenced from getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() is missing. That said, Ajax in Wicket usualy works perfect if done right in contrast to what your title's suggesting.

Comment: Probably the title is not perfect, but I cannot use "Problem with not working AJAX in wicket application" while Problem word is rejected to be in title... Of course I knew it's not wicket problem, but mine, but I couldn't see it... It's strange also that wicket has no problem with missing ajax indicator id as it usually complains when something is missing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are not using the `<body>` tag in your HTML. This breaks the HTML parsers and this is why you cannot see the AJAX debug window (and any other javascript behaviour).

There is a nice example of what you are trying to do at Wicket Examples, have a look at it:
http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/choice

Comment: Really, that was the problem, thank you ;-) I saw that page before, but link to source code is not working :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour` instead. The following is a section from my code which works -

```
DropDownChoice<String> actionSelect = new DropDownChoice<String>("myDropdown", updateActions, choiceRenderer);
actionSelect.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: and there is some difference in those two behaviors ?

Comment: Looks like not a lot really. AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviour is the superclass of OnChangeAjaxBehaviour